# Create a macro that extracts information from a temporal sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a master sheet in which i have to extract info from another one, this sheet is generated from XML file of a program created long time ago for the company but it automatically opens it up in excel.

That file is saved in some folder in the Programs(x86) folder, so the name will always change, also is not only one file, every time I open a new record it will be saved there

The things I need to extract, is a

```
=Max (Column X:X)
=Count (Y:Y)
=Sum (Y:Y) (From that same last one)
```

I recorded a macro, but for the file path it will get the one I recorded it with.

I don't know how to make it to be for the other excel sheet besides changing the file path manually

I was wondering if something like (if there is another sheet open extract it from there, making only 2 sheets to be open to avoid the code crashing?) can be created, or something else?

Also, the columns will always have the same name, but not the same position, could it be referenced with the name of the column?

This is the macro I recorded

```
 Sub test_2()
' test_2 Macro
' asdad
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
    ActiveCell.Select<br>
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MAX('ExportReport27d8b91d-bafc-4437-a37d-90e53df817f8.htm'!C5)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[TaxID]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=COUNT('ExportReport27d8b91d-bafc-4437-a37d-90e53df817f8.htm'!C11)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[TaxID]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM('ExportReport27d8b91d-bafc-4437-a37d-90e53df817f8.htm'!C11)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[TaxID]]").Select
End Sub
```

I'm also open for suggestions, maybe a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally got it working,

First a created this

```
Sub ExtractInfoOnTemp()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Extracts "Max","Count" & "Sum" From Temporal File
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[4])"
 Range("A1").Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
 Range("B1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(C[9])"
  Range("A1").Select

Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("C1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[8])"
  Range("C1").Select

Selection.Style = "Currency"
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

End Sub
```

This extracts the data on the sheet being worked on on the first row, there are only 3 values to it, Its not used directly

Then I created this one, whichs copy pastes it to the Master sheet, that on is constant so the name stays there, if anything I just change the name

```
Sub PrintInfoInMaster()
CurWkbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim c
Dim example As Range

Set example = Range("A1:C4")
Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ExtractInfoOnTemp"
ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("AllNonParSummary - MASTER.xlsx").Activate

'This is to look for the first empy cel from top to botom and select it     to paste the info
For Each c In Range("H:H").Cells 
If c = "" Then
c.Select
 Exit For
    End If

Next
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ProviderLastName]]").Select
Windows(CurWkbk).Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open a FileDialog and have the user navigate to the file.  Would that interest you?  Code example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865217.aspx

I adapted the above to one of my projects by setting the parameters of the dialog box to allow the user to pick from PDF files.  Here is my modified version:

```
Function PDFLocator(InitialPath As String) as String
    'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog

    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Declare a variable to contain the path
    'of each selected item. Even though the path is aString,
    'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
    'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fd
        ' Set up the dialog box
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "S&elect"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Scanned Document", "*.pdf", 1
        .Title = "File Dialog Box"
        .InitialFileName = InitialPath
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

        'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
        'The user pressed the button.
        If .Show = -1 Then

            'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

                'vrtSelectedItem is aString that contains the path of each selected item.
                'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
                'This example displays the path in a message box.
                'MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
                PDFLocator = vrtSelectedItem

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        'The user pressed Cancel.
        Else
        End If
    End With

    'Set the object variable to Nothing.
    Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

It is possible to locate columns based on the column name or header row.  You can use the Find method to get the range.column here is a line from one of my projects:

```
DataColNumber = wb.wks.Range("1:1").Find("Machine", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
```

Comment: Thanks, looking for the file will take the same time as if i would just write the formulas myself, the column name finder its perfect that will be really useful

Answer (score 0):

If the beginning of the file name will always be "ExportReport", and there will only ever be one "ExportReport" file in that folder, you could loop through all of the files in that folder, looking for just that bit of the filename.

```
Function GetFileName() as String
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("c:\[path to Programs(x86)]\")
   While (file <> "")
      If InStr(file, "ExportReport") > 0 Then 'This is looking for the string "ExportReport" in each filename, and will exit when it finds a file that matches.
         GetFileName = file
         Exit Sub
      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend
End Function
```

Then you can use the output of this in place of your filename. For example:

```
filename = GetFileName
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MAX('" & filename & "'!C5)"
```